# Neo4j cypher query with aggregate function returns incomplete result

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

everyone! I have a Neo4j database which contains information about visitors who visit a number of checkpoints at specific moments of time. visitors, visits and checkpoints are represented as nodes.

Each visitor is identified by his/her device MAC address, each checkpoint has a unique id.

Each visit node contains an EnterTime property, which is the time (num of millisec since 1970) when the visitor with some specific MAC address is first noticed near the respective checkpoint.

Note: the duration of a visit should be calculated as the difference between EnterTime of the next visit and the EnterTime of this visit. Each checkpoint may be visited more than once.

The database is created with this cypher query:

```
//Create visitors:
CREATE (Visitor1: Visitor {MAC:'00:0a:95:9d:68:16'})
CREATE (Visitor2: Visitor {MAC:'00:0a:95:9d:68:17'})
CREATE (Visitor3: Visitor {MAC:'00:0a:95:9d:68:18'})

//Create CheckPoints:
CREATE (CheckPoint1: CheckPoint {CheckPointId: 1})
CREATE (CheckPoint2: CheckPoint {CheckPointId: 2})
CREATE (CheckPoint3: CheckPoint {CheckPointId: 3})
CREATE (CheckPoint4: CheckPoint {CheckPointId: 4})
CREATE (CheckPoint5: CheckPoint {CheckPointId: 5})


//Create visits:
//by visitor 1:
CREATE  (Visitor1)-[:MAKES]->(Visit1: Visit {EnterTime: 1488358800000})-[:TO]->(CheckPoint1)
CREATE  (Visitor1)-[:MAKES]->(Visit2: Visit {EnterTime: 1488359400000})-[:TO]->(CheckPoint2)
CREATE  (Visitor1)-[:MAKES]->(Visit3: Visit {EnterTime: 1488361200000})-[:TO]->(CheckPoint3)
CREATE  (Visitor1)-[:MAKES]->(Visit4: Visit {EnterTime: 1488363600000})-[:TO]->(CheckPoint4)
CREATE  (Visitor1)-[:MAKES]->(Visit5: Visit {EnterTime: 1488364800000})-[:TO]->(CheckPoint5)
CREATE  (Visitor1)-[:MAKES]->(Visit6: Visit {EnterTime: 1488365400000})-[:TO]->(CheckPoint1)

//by visitor 2:
CREATE  (Visitor2)-[:MAKES]->(Visit7: Visit {EnterTime: 1488358800000})-[:TO]->(CheckPoint1)
CREATE  (Visitor2)-[:MAKES]->(Visit8: Visit {EnterTime: 1488360300000})-[:TO]->(CheckPoint4)
CREATE  (Visitor2)-[:MAKES]->(Visit9: Visit {EnterTime: 1488362400000})-[:TO]->(CheckPoint2)
CREATE  (Visitor2)-[:MAKES]->(Visit10: Visit {EnterTime: 1488363000000})-[:TO]->(CheckPoint1)

//by visitor 3:
CREATE  (Visitor3)-[:MAKES]->(Visit11: Visit {EnterTime: 1488353820000})-[:TO]->(CheckPoint1)
CREATE  (Visitor3)-[:MAKES]->(Visit12: Visit {EnterTime: 1488354600000})-[:TO]->(CheckPoint4)
CREATE  (Visitor3)-[:MAKES]->(Visit13: Visit {EnterTime: 1488358200000})-[:TO]->(CheckPoint3)
CREATE  (Visitor3)-[:MAKES]->(Visit14: Visit {EnterTime: 1488359700000})-[:TO]->(CheckPoint1)
```

I am writing a cypher query to find the total time of visits to each checkpoint. 
I am trying this one:

```
match (vr: Visitor)-->(v1: Visit)-->(cp1: CheckPoint),
 (vr)-->(v2: Visit)-->()
where v2.EnterTime > v1.EnterTime
with cp1.CheckPointId as CheckPointId,
     v1.EnterTime as EnterTime,
     min((v2.EnterTime - v1.EnterTime) / 60000) as visit_duration
return CheckPointId, sum(visit_duration) as total_visit_duration
order by CheckPointId;
```

The result should be:

```
cp1  - 48 min
cp2 – 40 min
cp3 – 65 min
cp4 – 115 min
cp5 – 10 min
```

But my query returns an incorrect result:

```
cp1  - 23 min
cp2 – 40 min
cp3 – 65 min
cp4 – 115 min
cp5 – 10 min
```

Obviously, the error is that the length of the visit by visitor (mac == 00:0a:95:9d:68:17) to the checkpoint with id == 1 is not taken into consideration. But it is my guess.

What is the problem with my query? How can it be improved to return the correct result?

Your help will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
match ()<--(v2:Visit)<--(vr: Visitor)-->(v1: Visit)-->(cp1: CheckPoint)
where v2.EnterTime > v1.EnterTime
with vr,
 cp1.CheckPointId as CheckPointId,
 v1.EnterTime as EnterTime,
 min((v2.EnterTime - v1.EnterTime) / 60000) as visit_duration
return CheckPointId, sum(visit_duration) as total_visit_duration
order by CheckPointId;
```

I added `vr` in `with` statement. Cypher groups by the all the values you put in `with` statement. The reason why your code didnt work is because `v1.EnterTime` for checkpoint 1 for visitor 1 and 2 is the same. Because you had only `EnterTime` and `CheckpointID` in `with` statement, cypher grouped by `EnterTime` and so because you have the `min(v2.EnterTime - v1.EnterTime)` it just took the smaller one and did not use both. Now that we introduce `Visitor` in the `with` statement, it will group by visitor also, which solves our problem, if two people start same checkpoint at same time.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! It solved the issue! I am very grateful for you help! Hope it will be useful to other people struggling with Neo4j and cypher.